# open InAppBrowser in popup in iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, cordova, inappbrowser

For payment gateway, i use inAppBrowser in iPhone app. inAppbrowser working very well. but i want this open in a popup that when it redirect after payment, i close this popup and my app continue.

Now inAppBrowser open but it open in like a new tab and my app close.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="payment()">payment</a>

 function payment() {
         var ref = window.open('http://myurl.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');

    }
```

i also use iframe but it not working. If any solution by iframe please suggest.

```
<div id="iframe" class="myACform" data-href="container-div"  style="display:none;">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:100%;height:100%">
     </iframe>
 </div>
```

Thnx
.

Comment: Which cordova version are you using? hope you added inAppBrowser API..

Comment: 3.3 version, i am using